# Job trigger not pushing at set time

Tags: powershell

Created a script to set a desktop background at 4pm but the scheduled job isn't running at 4pm. The end result I'll need it to run on a monthly basis to change the background but currently cannot get the conditions to run whilst testing

```
$Trigger = New-JobTrigger -Daily -At "4:00pm"
Register-ScheduledJob -Trigger $Trigger -RunAs32 -ScriptBlock {

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "templink" -UseBasicParsing -OutFile "C:/Users/Public/Wallpaper.jpg"

$MyWallpaper="C:\Users\Public\Wallpaper.jpg"
$code = @' 
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 
namespace Win32{ 
    
     public class Wallpaper{ 
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)] 
         static extern int SystemParametersInfo (int uAction , int uParam , string lpvParam , int fuWinIni) ; 
         
         public static void SetWallpaper(string thePath){ 
            SystemParametersInfo(20,0,thePath,3); 
         }
    }
 } 
'@

add-type $code 
[Win32.Wallpaper]::SetWallpaper($MyWallpaper)
} -Name Wallpaper
```

Comment: Check Event Viewer to see if there are any errors.  I assume code runs if it is not scheduled.  Usually schedule jobs fail because the default account is System which has no environmental variables.  You should create a service account which has the correct environment and then start task using the service account.

Comment: What does the task scheduler history say?  You should also be able to do `powershell script.ps1 > log 2>&1`

Comment: @js2010 I checked the scheduler history and there's nothing appearing under the name I've given the task at all but then when running the code again in the powershell ISE I get an error of it already exists